# Why does XGrabKey return BadRequest?

Tags: gtk, x11

So I'm working on a Gtk/X11/Linux [app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WyVw.png) that does screen capture to .gif and one of the methods of stopping the capture is a key press (Esc, Space or End). You can also use a timeout. However to implement the key press to end capture I have to be able to grab the key such that I can get an event even though my window doesn't have focus (it's actually invisible during capture). I believe [XGrabKey](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabKey.html) is the right X11 function for this task:

```
Window w = Gtk::gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid(Gtk::gtk_widget_get_window(Handle()));
KeyCode kc = XKeysymToKeycode(Gtk::gdk_display, HotKeyCode);
int r = XGrabKey(   Gtk::gdk_display,
                    kc,
                    0               /* modifiers */,
                    w               /* grab_window */,
                    TRUE            /* owner_events */,
                    GrabModeAsync   /* pointer_mode */,
                    GrabModeAsync   /* keyboard_mode */);
printf("XGrabKey(%p, 0x%x/%x)=%i\n", w, HotKeyCode, kc, r);
```

Where 'HotKeyCode' is say XK_Escape or something e.g.:

```
XGrabKey(0x3e00003, 0xff1b/9)=1
```

XGrabKey is returning '1' or BadRequest. What am I doing wrong here?

FYI the actual Xorg Xserver code in question appears to be [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/tree/dix/events.c#n5013).

Edit: The latest incarnation of the code is:

```
int x_err_callback(Display *d, XErrorEvent *e)
{
    char msg[256];

    XGetErrorText(d, e->error_code, msg, sizeof(msg));

    printf("X11Error %d (%s): request %d.%d\n",
        e->error_code, msg, e->request_code,
        e->minor_code);

    return 0;
}

Gtk::GdkFilterReturn key_filter(Gtk::GdkXEvent *gdk_xevent,
                                Gtk::GdkEvent *event,
                                Gtk::gpointer data)
{
    XKeyEvent *xevent = gdk_xevent;
    if (xevent->type == KeyPress)
    {
        int key = ((XKeyEvent *)gdk_xevent)->keycode;
        int keysym = XKeycodeToKeysym(Gtk::gdk_display, key, 0);

        printf("caught keysym %i\n", keysym);

        switch (keysym)
        {
            case 1: // your_keysym
                // your key handler code
                break;
        }
    }

    return Gtk::GDK_FILTER_CONTINUE;
}


Gtk::GdkWindow *Root = Gtk::gdk_get_default_root_window();
KeyCode kc = XKeysymToKeycode(Gtk::gdk_display, HotKeyCode);

XSetErrorHandler(x_err_callback);

int r = XGrabKey(   Gtk::gdk_display,
                    kc,
                    AnyModifier /* modifiers */,
                    GDK_WINDOW_XWINDOW(Root) /* grab_window */,
                    TRUE            /* owner_events */,
                    GrabModeAsync   /* pointer_mode */,
                    GrabModeSync    /* keyboard_mode */);

Gtk::gdk_window_set_events(Root,
    (Gtk::GdkEventMask)
    (Gtk::GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK |
    Gtk::GDK_KEY_RELEASE_MASK));
Gtk::gdk_window_add_filter(NULL, key_filter, this);
```

AnyModifier actually results in an error. '0' doesn't. I know about the NumLock issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A return value of `1` does *not* mean that a BadRequest error occured. [Xlib handles errors via an error handler](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/protocol-errors/default-handlers.html), and the function will *always* return `1`, if it returns at all.

Your code does not work because you have to do the `XGrabKey` on the root window (`GetDefaultRootWindow(Gtk::gdk_display)`). Here's a pure Xlib demo:

```c
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    Display *d = XOpenDisplay(0);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(d);
    int keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(d, XK_BackSpace);

    int rv = XGrabKey(d, keycode, AnyModifier, root, 1, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);
    printf("XGrabKey returned %d\n", rv);

    XEvent evt;
    while(1) {
        XNextEvent(d, &evt);
        printf("Got event %d\n", evt.type);
    }
}
```

To then capture the X11 events from GTK use `gdk_window_add_filter` on a `NULL` or on the root window and a `GdkFilterFunc` that processes the events associated with your global hotkey:

```c
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>
#include <stdio.h>

GdkFilterReturn filter(GdkXEvent *xevent, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data) {
    XKeyEvent *ev = (XKeyEvent *)xevent;
    if(ev->type == 2) {
        printf("Backspace hit.\n");
    }

    return GDK_FILTER_CONTINUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GdkScreen *scr = gdk_screen_get_default();
    GdkWindow *groot = gdk_screen_get_root_window(scr);
    gdk_window_set_events(groot, GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK);
    gdk_window_add_filter(groot, filter, NULL);

    Display *d = gdk_x11_get_default_xdisplay();
    Window root = GDK_WINDOW_XID(groot);
    int keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(d, XK_BackSpace);
    XGrabKey(d, keycode, AnyModifier, root, 1, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);

    gtk_main();
}
```

As a side note, a modifier mask of `0` means that *no* modifiers must be enabled, even those that would not modify the meaning of a key. A grab on the letter "A" with a `0` modifier would not match NumLock + A. That's why I used `AnyModifer`.

Comment: I've spent a few hours tried to get gdk_window_add_filter working on the root window and no luck. It doesn't send my callback any events. Even when I call gdk_window_set_events(root_win, ...) first with KeyPress/KeyRelease masks. As for the Window to pass to XGrabKey I'm doing GDK_WINDOW_XID(root)... where root is from gdk_get_default_root_window(). Seems like no-one has ever done this from a GTK app before. It does seem like you are on the right track, it's just not getting me over the line. (I did setup the error handler too... it's not showing anything interesting)

Comment: In a standalone X11 process your code works (minus the AnyModifier parameter). I can't make it work in the context of my GTK app though. What I might do for the time being is run a sub-process to do the keyboard hook and use your code as a template.

Comment: Works for me. I'll add a second example (in C) that runs in the GTK main loop.